# Calculate $\int_{0}^{1}\left \{ \sqrt{1-x^2}+2 \right \}^2 dx$

Tags: integration

I couldn't find any suitable substitution for this integral and hence I couldn't solve it.

$$\int_{0}^{1}\left \{ \sqrt{1-x^2}+2 \right \}^2 dx$$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint**: Expand the integrand.

You get three terms, two of which can be integrated easily. The one term that isn't as easy is $\int_0^1 4 \sqrt { 1-x^2}\, dx.$ But that one is the area of the unit circle!

Comment: I have done same thing but I couldn't integrate that one!!

Comment: But you don't have to. What is the function of $x$ that defines the upper half of the unit circle?

Comment: it is $\sin(x)$

Comment: No, the unit circle is $x^2 +y^2 =1.$ What is $y$ in terms of $x$ for the upper semicircle?

Comment: I found it by substituting x=sin(t) and intervals from 0 to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and result is only $\pi$ because of 4 in front of integral.

Comment: What I'm saying is this: $\int_0^1\sqrt {1-x^2}\, dx = \pi/4$ is obvious if you recognize the function $y = \sqrt {1-x^2}$ as the Cartesian equation of the top half of the unit circle. No substitution, no worry, no work, no nothing. It's the unit circle!

Comment: @zhw But these go to 11 ... ;-))

Comment: @Dr.MV Are you referring to Spinal Tap?

Comment: @zhw Yes.  Given the previous set of comments, I thought it was reminiscent

Comment: @zhw.  The reference was This is Spinal Tap; "I mean, it's not your job to be as confused as Nigel."  And it seems that the "Who's on first" sketch applies equally well with Lou taking Nigel's place ;-)) - Mark

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{0}^{1}\left \{ \sqrt{1-x^2}+2 \right \}^2 dx$$

$$ = \int_{0}^{1} 1-x^2 + 4\sqrt{1-x^2} + 4  dx$$

$$ = \int_{0}^{1} 5-x^2 + 4\sqrt{1-x^2}dx$$

$$ = \int_{0}^{1} 5-x^2 dx + 4\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1-x^2}dx$$

To integrate $\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1-x^2}dx$, use [trigonometric substitution](http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/integration/trigsub/trigsub.html):

Let $x = \sin(\theta)$. Then eventually we get $\pi/4$ according to [this](http://www.integral-calculator.com/) (I can't use Wolfram for some reason).